# How to add self-descrptive text to swagger using Camel Java SQL

Tags: java, apache-camel, swagger, swagger-ui

This Java DSL for specifying REST endpoint in camel 2.15

```js
rest("/path/")
                .get({"{id}")
                .produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                .description("My Comment")
                .to("direct:myroute");
```

comes back with this swagger json with EMPTY description despite specifying a description in the DSL above;

```js
{"apiVersion":"1.2.3","swaggerVersion":"1.2","apis":[{"path":"/path/","description":""}]}
```

Please, does anyone know how to put a swagger description in the java DSL so that it shows in the swagger json and then the swagger UI?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with 2.15.1 release

Comment: Thanks but It didn't work!

Comment: Does anyone have a clue on how this works with Java DSL? It appears to me that .description("My Comment") does not provide the description for swagger.

Comment: It seems oddly for me, but when Camel parses verb definition it fills operation "summary" field instead of "description" as follows:
            if (verb.getDescriptionText() != null) {
                op.summary(verb.getDescriptionText());
            }